# How to select input Value empty and not empty using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select **input:empty** and **input:not(:empty)** value after click on submit button and add following conditions:

1. If **value is empty**, after click change background color.

   *(It's not working as you can see in the **input Text3**)*
2. If **value is not empty**, after click add these three conditions:

   *(It's not working in my sample code)*

•   {cursor: not-allowed;} 
•   readonly
•   Change Background color

Here is my sample code:

```js
  $(".signupbtn").on('click', function() {
      $("input").filter(function() {
          return this.value.length !== 0;
      }).val("Successfully Received!");
      $("input:empty")
          .css("background", "rgb(255,220,200)");

      $("input:not(:empty)").style.cursor = "not-allowed";
      $("input:not(:empty)")
          .css("background", "rgb(220,20,60)");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" name="firstname" value="">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" name="firstname" value="">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" name="firstname" value="sss">
 <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: You’re already using `.css` correctly. Now read the error in the console and correct that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version of your code. First select all the `input` tags with `type of text` then see if their `length is 0 or not` on this apply what you want to it.

```js
$(".signupbtn").on('click', function() {
   $('input:text').each(function(){
   
      if($(this).val().length == 0 ){
        $(this).css("background", "red");
      }else{
        $(this).val("Successfully Received!");
        $(this).css("background", "green");
        $(this).css("cursor","not-allowed");
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" name="firstname" value="">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" name="firstname" value="">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" name="firstname" value="sss">
 <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Andam, nice way to select all input tags first. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(".signupbtn").on('click', function() {
      $("input").filter(function() {
          return this.value.length !== 0;
      }).val("Successfully Received!");
      $("input:empty")
          .css("background", "rgb(255,220,200)");

      $("input:not(:empty)").css("cursor","not-allowed");
      $("input:not(:empty)")
          .css("background", "rgb(220,20,60)");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" name="firstname" value="">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" name="firstname" value="">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" name="firstname" value="sss">
 <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
 </form>
```